The zoom value resets every time I release the screen in InteractiveViewer Flutter
I want to show the red square when I zoom and the value is greater than two. With the code I have I can do it, the problem is that when I release the screen, the zoom resets and the square disappears.
How can I make the square stay on after stopping zooming, as long as the zoom is greater than two and of course, disappear if the zoom value is less than two?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ZoomProvider(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Interactive Viewer Example',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Zoom ${context.watch<ZoomProvider>().zoomLevel.toStringAsFixed(1)}'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
              onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
                context.read<ZoomProvider>().updateZoomLevel(details.scale);
              },
              boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(320),
              constrained: false,
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 5.0,
              child: Stack(
                children: [Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              
            
            
            Visibility(
              //visible: true,
              visible: context.watch<ZoomProvider>().zoomLevel >= 2,
              child: Container(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            ]
              )
        
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ZoomProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _zoomLevel = 1.0;

  double get zoomLevel => _zoomLevel;

  void updateZoomLevel(double scale) {
    _zoomLevel = scale;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


You need to store the zoom level persistently in the ZoomProvider.
You can achieve this by separating the state update during the interaction and the final state update once the interaction is complete. Like this:
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Zoom ${context.watch<ZoomProvider>().zoomLevel.toStringAsFixed(1)}'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
            context.read<ZoomProvider>().updateZoomLevel(details.scale);
          },
          onInteractionEnd: (details) {
            context.read<ZoomProvider>().finalizeZoomLevel();
          },
          boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(320),
          constrained: false,
          minScale: 0.5,
          maxScale: 5.0,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: context.watch<ZoomProvider>().isZoomedIn,
                child: Container(
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ZoomProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _zoomLevel = 1.0;
  double _finalZoomLevel = 1.0;

  double get zoomLevel => _zoomLevel;
  bool get isZoomedIn => _finalZoomLevel >= 2;

  void updateZoomLevel(double scale) {
    _zoomLevel = scale;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void finalizeZoomLevel() {
    _finalZoomLevel = _zoomLevel;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

As you see in the picture below, the red container remains.


Thank you very much for your fast response, I understand the concept you mention, but I can't make it work. If I copy the code you added, it still doesn't work. Where is the error located?
